# How to add a Joystick from Standard Assets in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, joystick

I am totally a beginner in Unity (Downloaded Unity 3 days ago). I created a simple game and I can move the player with keyboard by using this code -

```
void FixedUpdate () {
            float speed = 250;
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

However, I want to play the game in **Android** and for that I need to use joystick. Can anyone tell me how to use the joystick in Standard Assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me has helped [this Asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233). There's also a video tutorial on implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Remove Time.deltaTime, Time.deltaTime is for Update() not for FixedUpdate()...